# jmeter text resp. assertion failing when appears it should pass

Tags: jmeter

I'm getting a very basic text resp failing in jmeter when it appears it should pass.  Feels like some whitespace or character encoding issue, but got me stuck - any pointers would be great.

- Applied to: HTTP sampler
- Type of assert: Main sample only, text resp
- Matching: equals

So I ran the sample with the asset disabled, and copied the content of the resp. body into the patterns to test field within the asset.  The context should be static, so assumed it would pass.

However, the assert is tripping with:
Assertion failure message: Test failed: text expected to equal.

URL testing:- http://c1-orig-qa.adis.ws/c/AutomatedQA2/texttype_plain.xml

Comment: Please give us the exact assertion string and an example response on which it fails. (did you try to check manually on result tree view?)

Comment: And the html response that you ran this on? Pastebin would work.

Comment: Added both the assert string and the message from the fail in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/6wl/2972efe7607e4c16f2b0#file-gistfile1-txt

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to compare full xml as even 2 xmls that differ in whitespace should be equal. 
Most probably here the issue is whitespace.

I suggest you just compare some texts line:
- ok
- [CDATA[/c/AutomatedQA2/texttype_plain]]>

Comment: Well discounting the fact it was XML (and if I really wanted to do an XML check I'd use dtd or check for specific node), all I was really doing was checking the resp body of a request to be a specific value.  

The resp doesn't change between re-runs and I copied the resp body exactly from the resp listed in the tree view, however, upon doing the string comparison with that against the same request, the asset fails.  

Similar tests worked using json and regular text, so was unsure why a string comparison might fail in this instance.